# Function to loop through all worksheets to find value, return worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function that:

- Takes in one cell as a parameter
- Looks to see if the cell is in column A
- - If true, return the worksheet name
- - If false, moves to the next worksheet and tries again

I've tried a few different ways but I can't get it to work.  Currently, this is where I'm at:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function codeLookup(cellOne)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim findValue As Boolean

    With WorksheetFunction
        findValue = .VLookup(cellOne, ws.Range("A:A"), 1)
    End With

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       If findValue = True Then
       codeLookup = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
       End If
       Next

End Function
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it-

```
Public Function codeLookup(cellOne)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim findValue As Variant

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
findValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cellOne, ws.Range("A:A"), 1)
   If findValue <> "" Then
   codeLookup = ws.Name
   Exit Function
   End If
Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting closer when you submitted this and saw some easy errors in my code (like not doing the vlookup function right).  I was still a bit off though; you helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use the Range.Find Function. (I dont know what's faster)

For example:

```
Public Function codeLookup(cellOne) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchRange As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set searchRange = ws.Columns(1).Find(what:=cellOne, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not searchRange Is Nothing Then
            codeLookup = ws.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    codeLookup = "No match found"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I like being able to see other ways to write it; it helps understand the structure of the code.  I like that this way returns a "No Match Found" option instead of just a 0.