# Find and Replace whole Workbook in VBA without loop?

Tags: excel, vba

Using the build in Find&Replace function in Excel and setting it to search in the whole workbooks works much faster that using VBA and searching each worksheet though a loop. When I record the macro it only give me VBA code that goes though the active sheet and not the whole workbook. Is there a VBA solution that works just as fast as the build in function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to loop through all worksheets to find value, return worksheet name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637874/function-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-to-find-value-return-worksheet-name)

Comment: @braX I know how to do it, I am just wondering it is slower that the build in Excel solution and I would love to replicate that one.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could post your (macro-recorded) code. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62357216/edit) your question.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this, then all "b" in the whole Workbook get replaced by "k".

```vb
Sub test()

    Cells.Replace What:="b", Replacement:="k", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: @Valentin yes it does

Comment: I have exactly the same code (from the Macro Recorder) but it only finds and replaces values in the active sheet.

Comment: @Valentin Strange. Could you post your code? Otherwise you could loop over the worksheets in the workbook, should still be quite fast (depending on the amount of data your searching through).

Comment: This is dependent on the "Within" option being set to "Workbook".